HTTPClient with NTLM authentication not working in dotnet web application
I have a web server I'm working on using dotnet 7, and I need to hit an external API which uses NTLM authentication.
This is a snippet from my program.cs
private static WebApplicationBuilder CreateWebApplication(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>()
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(_ => CreateHandler("myuser", "mypass"));
    builder.services.AddControllers();
}

private static HttpClientHandler CreateHandler(string username, string password) 
{
    return new HttpClientHandler {
        PreAuthenticate = true,
        UseProxy = false,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new CredentialsCache 
        {
            {
                new Uri("http://myendpoint", "Negotiate", new NetworkCredential(username, password))
            }
        }
    }
}

This is a snippet from my service
public class MyService
{
    private HttpClient _client;
    public MyService(HttpClient client) 
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task Run() 
    {
        HttpRequestMessage req = GenerateHttpReq();
        HttpResponseMessage res = await _client.SendAsync(req);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to send request. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
        // ... some more processing
    }
}

When I run my app, the Run() method in the service gets called, but an exception is thrown Failed to send request. Status code: Unauthorized.
In order to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong with the http client creation, I've written a small app that does work
var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
        PreAuthenticate = true,
        UseProxy = false,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new CredentialsCache 
        {
            {
                new Uri("http://myendpoint"), "Negotiate", new NetworkCredential(username, password)
            }
        }

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var res = await client.PostAsync("http://myendpoint",new StringContent(""));

The above request is authenticated with the server successfully.
I should note, I am running my project on and Ubuntu 22 machine. When running the little test application on my Ubuntu machine it fails, but when running it on a windows machine it does work. We deploy our project to a Linux based container so I need it to work on Linux.

@Charlieface Not really sure what you mean by actual local user, we have a service account for this. Where should we add a using statement?

Is the service account a local user (on the server machine) or an AD domain user? You put using before all the disposable objects using HttpRequestMessage req = and using HttpResponseMessage res = and using var client = etc

@Charlieface It is an AD domain service user

Try new NetworkCredential(username, password, domainNameHere)

Adding the domain doesn't help unfortunately.

Are you sure it's using NTLM, and not locked to Kerberos? Try a Wireshark trace and see if you can see what's going on.

@Charlieface I captured traffic using wireshark and saw that after sending the POST request, the server response with 401 and WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate header, which from what I understand from this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76771029/401-unauthorized-while-using-identity-authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-ne is the correct first step, but for some reason my code throws an exception at that point.

@Charlieface I can also see that the client isn't sending an Authorisation header in the request. Also, the socket isn't closed, no FIN is sent.

Did you mean { new Uri("http://myendpoint"), "Negotiate", new NetworkCredential(username, password) } not { new Uri("http://myendpoint", "Negotiate", new NetworkCredential(username, password)) } and are you sure that URI matches what you are sending?

@Charlieface yeah you're right, typo when copying the code, fixed it in the question. Also, yes, the URI is correct.

@Charlieface I also captured traffic when using NTLM on a different application which works. I saw that the server first responds with a 401, and then the client re-sends the request with an Authorization header and the flow continues as normal

The FIN is probably not sent because you have no using on the request and response. I'm not sure but it sounds like it's not finding the credential in the cache or something. Try debugging with Just My Code switched off (and load the .NET source code from Microsoft servers)

Posting an answer just in case someone runs into the same issue as me.
The solution to my problem was to use .NET 8.0 and add the following to my .csproj file
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfiguration Include="System.Net.Security.UseManagedNtlm" Value="true"/>
</ItemGroup>

I will note that I am running my project on the official dotnet docker image using dotnet/sdk:8.0-jammy for building the project and dotnet/aspnet:8.0-jammy for deploying

Strangely enough, I could not get it to work just by adding things to the project file. However, enabling it from the code did the trick: AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Security.UseManagedNtlm", true);
This thread helped me a lot: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/101058

@KasparsOzols Interseting. Your method and my method essentially do the same thing.
